# Resharper indenting comments between if and corresponding else

Tags: resharper, resharper-4.5

I am looking for the setting to tell Resharper to not indent comments that come between an if and its corresponding else.

Example:

```
if()
{
}
    //Resharper keeps indenting this line
else
{
}
```

I want it to format like this:

```
if()
{
}
//The comment should line up with the braces and the "else"
else
{
}
```

I've gone through the Resharper indenting and line settings but am unable to find the correct settings.  What settings do I need to set to get the desired formatting?

Comment: I dont think my r# does this. Maybe you should update to 5.1

Comment: Yes! 5.1 does this and it is annoying!

Comment: It doesn't do this for me. It might be related to your settings in Visual Studio itself; to be honest though, putting a comment in here violates a StyleCop rule (SA1108), so if this is a bug/omission in Resharper, it's unlikely to get fixed.